# how to display Dialog box Like Fragment in activity

Tags: android, android-fragments, datepicker

i want to display date Dialog Picker Like This Image 
[image]

I m able To Open Dialog box with the Help Of Code but that look Like old Version Of Datepicker

i want datepicker Like Image Which I posted

here is My DateDilogefragment.java

```
public class DateDialogFragment extends SherlockDialogFragment {    

public static String TAG = "DateDialogFragment";
static Context mContext; 
static int mYear;
static int mMonth;
static int mDay;
static DateDialogFragmentListener mListener;


public static DateDialogFragment newInstance(Context context, DateDialogFragmentListener listener, Calendar now) {
    DateDialogFragment dialog = new DateDialogFragment();
    mContext = context;
    mListener = listener;       
    mYear = now.get(Calendar.YEAR);
    mMonth = now.get(Calendar.MONTH);
    mDay = now.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);      
    return dialog;
}


public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    return new DatePickerDialog(mContext, mDateSetListener, mYear, mMonth, mDay);
}


private OnDateSetListener mDateSetListener = new OnDateSetListener() {      
    @Override
    public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int monthOfYear, int dayOfMonth) {
        mYear = year;
        mMonth = monthOfYear;
        mDay = dayOfMonth;          
        mListener.updateChangedDate(year, monthOfYear, dayOfMonth);
    }


};


public interface DateDialogFragmentListener {
    public void updateChangedDate(int year, int month, int day);
}

}
```

and My Activity Class

```
        btn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                showDatePickerDialog();
            }
        });



    }



    public void showDatePickerDialog() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
         now = Calendar.getInstance();   
        DateDialogFragment frag = DateDialogFragment.newInstance(
                this, new DateDialogFragment.DateDialogFragmentListener() {
            public void updateChangedDate(int year, int month, int day) {
               tv.setText(String.valueOf(day) + "-" + String.valueOf(month+1) + "-" +  String.valueOf(year));                               
                now.set(year, month, day);
              //pet.setBirthdate(birthdate.getText().toString());
            }
        }, 
        now);
        FragmentManager fm =  getSupportFragmentManager();
        frag.show(fm, "DateDialogFragment");   
    }
}
```

can You Please tell What I m Doing Wrong ..why my Dialog box is open like Old Version??

mine Is Open Like 
[image]

thanKu in adavance

Comment: I think that depand on OS version of device

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your application theme:

```
 <style name="AppTheme" parent="android:Theme.Holo.Light">
       <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
 </style>
```

This should resolve your problem.

Comment: But How Remove My Title Bar

Comment: i tried
  getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
        WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);

    // Hide the Title bar of this activity screen
    getWindow().requestFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);

but Not Workign Not Hiding My Tital Bar

Answer (score 0):

This date picker is in older devices, new API levels provide Light Theme. And your theme is dark black. if you will run your APP in device which has API above 14 (May be it is implemented in Honeycomb).
So change your style to `Theme.Light`. You can check your style in Value folders.

Comment: I have Galaxy Ace which has API lvl 10 (2.3.6) gingerbread. It shows me same black Picker and if i try in Emulator above API 14 it shows me Light colored Pickers.